# What can I do with the pressed grapes (mash) after getting the juice out?

Tags: mash, wine

What can I do with the pressed grapes after getting the juice for making wine?  It smells so good.  It seems a shame to just throw it all away.

Comment: One option would be to compost it.  I'm guessing this answer isn't in the spirit of your question.  But, it's still better than throwing it away!

Answer (score 1):

Although I have not done wine myself, if I ever did I would take the mash and make Grappa, Marc, Raki or one of those similiarities.

I found an eHow on how to make grappa; [eHow - How to Make Grappa](http://www.ehow.com/how_5200368_make-grappa-home.html).

As far as I can see, if there was something (that tastes) better to do with it then Grappa probably wouldn't exist =)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make Grappa or the like, crushed mash makes excellent compost. I remember taking wheel barrows full to the garden for my grandfather each year.